# Can I create a user-scoped S3 policy for use with unauthenticated AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

AWS doc tells you how to get a STS token using Cognito APIs GetID and GetOpenIdToken, and STS API AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity. In this process AWS does give you an IdentityId.

A common way to scope S3 access per-user is to assign a prefix in the policy that denotes the user.

Now the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity API will let you attach a user-scoped policy - but in this case we want to call this API **from the mobile client** - not usable due to security concerns.

Is there a way that I can build some sort of template that builds the prefix using IdentityId, or must I construct a server and put it in the middle to make this safe?

Answer (score 0):

While `AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity` does take a policy, this is a **scope down** policy on top of the existing policy on the role you are assuming and is **optional**. The permissions on the role cannot be expanded by this policy, only restricted. If you do not supply an additional scope down policy, the base policy for the role will be used.

You can use an access policy like the following to ensure your users can only upload (and list) a specific prefix based on their Cognito ID:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Action":["s3:PutObject","s3:GetObject","s3:DeleteObject"],
        "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/*"
      },
      {
        "Effect":"Allow",
        "Action":"s3:ListBucket",
        "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME",
        "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":"${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}/"}}
      }
   ]
}
```